# Using a delimited string, how do I get an array item relative to the parsed string?

Tags: php, arrays

Given a string in the format of "one/two" or "one/two/three", with / as delimiters, I need to get the value (as a reference) in a 2d array. In this specific case, I'm accessing the `$_SESSION` variable.

In the `SessionAccessor::getData($str)` function, I don't know what to put in there to make it parse the delimited string and return the array item. The idea is I won't know which array key I'm accessing. The function will be generic.

```
class SessionAccessor {
    static &function getData($str) {
         // $str = 'one/two/three'
         return $_SESSION['one']['two']['three'];
    }
}

/** Below is an example of how it will be expected to work **/
/**********************************************************/
// Get a reference to the array
$value =& SessionAccessor::getData('one/two/three');

// Set the value of $_SESSION['one']['two']['three'] to NULL
$value = NULL;
```

Comment: Setting the value would require a function - $value is not a pointer to a node in $_SESSION `SessionAccessor::setData('one/two/three', $value);`

Comment: I'm able to access the session using references like that. Even a `setData()` function would work. I just don't know what needs to go in there to set an array item given the / delimited string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning a reference to a session variable from the eval() function in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919476/returning-a-reference-to-a-session-variable-from-the-eval-function-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution provided by @RocketHazmat [here at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919476/returning-a-reference-to-a-session-variable-from-the-eval-function-in-php):

```
class SessionAccessor {
    static function &getVar($str) {
        $arr =& $_SESSION;
        foreach(explode('/',$str) as $path){
            $arr =& $arr[$path];
        }
        return $arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't fulfil the question. `// Set the value of $_SESSION['one']['two']['three'] to NULL`

Comment: Using the above function, if I set `$value =& SessionAccessor::getVar('one/two/three')`, then I can set `$value = NULL`, in turn setting `$_SESSION['one']['two']['three']` since `'one/two/three'` was inputted into the function.

Comment: Are you saying you can pull the value from an array as `$value`, then set that value to NULL and it will magically know where it got that value from and set that too? `$_SESSION['one']['two']['three']` will not be changed.

Comment: Actually, this solution works quite nicely too. Perhaps you could have taken the time to test this one as well Popnoodles: https://eval.in/157331. You may want to read up a little on references http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described, it sounds like this is what you're after;

```
&function getData($str) {
    $path = explode('/', $str);
    $value = $_SESSION;
    foreach ($path as $key) {
        if (!isset($value[$key])) {
            return null;
        }
        $value = $value[$key];
    }
    return $value;
}
```

**EDIT**

To also allow for the values to be set, it would be best to use a `setData` method. This should hopefully do what you hoped for;

```
class SessionAccessor {

    static function getData($str) {
        $path = explode('/', $str);
        $value = $_SESSION;
        foreach ($path as $key) {
            if (!isset($value[$key])) {
                return null;
            }
            $value = $value[$key];
        }
        return $value;
    }

    static function setData($str, $newValue) {
        $path = explode('/', $str);
        $last = array_pop($path);
        $value = &$_SESSION;
        foreach ($path as $key) {
            if (!isset($value[$key])) {
                $value[$key] = array();
            }
            $value = &$value[$key];
        }
        $value[$last] = $newValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: OP also wants to set the value

Comment: There's an example here that shows a very similar function answered for another question. https://eval.in/156443 but writing a function to set the value never happened. I was thinking of using `eval()`

Comment: I'll revisit the `eval()` function. The link in your comment gives me an internal server error. So I'm unable to see the example code there.

Comment: It's virtually the same as the code in this answer. I had expected Pudge601 to revisit, since they posted an answer, and complete the answer.

Comment: Hadn't seen the bit about setting the value. I would strongly recommend using a separate `setData` method for setting the value if this is what you're trying to do. Is there any reason why this would not be suitable?

Comment: That won't set the node in the array, it will just set the value of what you pulled from it. `$_SESSION['one']['two']['three']` will not be changed

Comment: Care to test that? It works fine for me, notice the use of `&` to get references to the values. Tested by changing `$_SESSION` to a static `$session` property following the same array structure. See https://eval.in/157325

Comment: It may or may not work, but it's simpler to use one function and return a reference to the array item.

Comment: Using one function returning a reference is definitely closer to what was asked for. Whether the solution is simpler/better is a bit more subjective, and more of a code review question; but I will say that there are myriad good reasons why the getter/setter design pattern is so prevalent over the getter returning a reference..