# Returning a reference to a session variable from the eval() function in PHP

Tags: php, session, pass-by-reference

Do you know how to return a reference to a `$_SESSION` variable from the `eval()` function.

```
class SessionAccessor {
    static function &getVar() {
        return eval('return $_SESSION["sample"];');
    }
}
```

Error checking aside, here is the result I want:

```
$sample =& SessionAccessor::getVar();
$sample = 'new value'; // sets $_SESSION['sample'] to 'new value'
```

If you're wondering whether or not I need to use `eval()`, the answer is yes.

Comment: The more important question is why are you trying to do this? Why do you think you need to use `eval()`? What is it you are actually trying to do? can you explain your use case?

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't really make sense. Sure passing by reference is possible in PHP but the way you're doing it simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please see [link](http://goo.gl/RWcyCD) for the full solution I'm after. Using `eval()` I can can build the string `"$_SESSION['one']['two']['three']"` from the string `"one/two/three"` since I don't know how to access the array item as a reference any other way.

Comment: `return &$_SESSION["sample"];`?  Does that not work?  What is the *EXACT* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: It produces a syntax error. I have `static function &getItem($str) {}` where `$str` is in the format `'csv/lines/0'`. The idea is to return a reference to an item in `$_SESSION`. In that case, it will be `$_SESSION['csv']['lines'][0]`. Building the string to use for `eval()` is easy.

Comment: @CodyHelscel: I think the fact that you have `'csv/lines/0'` is something that **needs** to be added into the question.  Can you edit the question and add that?  It's best to show us in the question what you *really* have.

Comment: `A return statement will immediately terminate the evaluation of the code.` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class SessionAccessor {
    static function &getVar($str) {
        $arr =& $_SESSION;
        foreach(explode('/',$str) as $path){
            $arr =& $arr[$path];
        }
        return $arr;
    }
}
```

You just need to loop over the path you want to get from the array and keep updating a reference to it.  Then return that reference.

DEMO: http://codepad.org/mUS26ZAG

Comment: Using that same method doesn't quite return a reference to the session variable from the `eval()` function.

Comment: @CodyHelscel: What are you talking about?

Comment: Yes that's perfectly suited for my needs. It solves everything, and it's so simple too. From that simple function, I'm able to access a reference to an array item from a delimited string.

Comment: Glad I could help! :-D